# C# generic graph search framework

Tags: c#, search, graph

I have now coded up various graph search (A*, DFS, BFS, etc..) algorithms many times over. Every time, the only real difference is the actual search states I am searching over, and how new states are generated from existing ones.

I am now faced with yet another search-heavy project, and would like to avoid having to code and debug a general search algorithm again. It would be really nice if I could define a search state class, including information for generating successive states, heuristic cost, etc, and just plug it in to some kind of existing search framework that can do all of the heavy lifting for me. I know the algorithms aren't particularly difficult to code, but there are always enough tricks involved to make it annoying.

Does anything like this exist? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Surely it wouldn't be too hard to generify one of your existing solutions? All you require for a pathfinding algorithm is a start state, an end state, and a function which takes a state and returns (with weights) all possible next states.

Comment: I don't have a solution in c# yet. Most I have now are java or c implementations from college. Translation is a little harder than generificating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) will be of interest.

> QuickGraph provides generic
>   directed/undirected graph
>   datastructures and algorithms for .Net
>   2.0 and up. QuickGraph comes with algorithms such as depth first seach,
>   breath first search, A* search,
>   shortest path, k-shortest path,
>   maximum flow, minimum spanning tree,
>   least common ancestors, etc

Comment: I like this, but it looks like it operates on an existing dataset. I need to dynamically generate future states from an infinite set of possibilities.

Comment: The dataset example is just one. You can create dynamic graphs.

Comment: wow. digging in, that looks quite powerful. It may take a bit of effort to learn the framework, but it looks like it should do everything I need.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a perfect use case for either a [Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28VS.80%29.aspx) or a [Lambda Expression.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

**Using Lambda Expressions for Tree Traversal – C#**  
http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2010/05/using-lambda-expressions-for-tree.html